# Как сделать неизменяемую ссылку?

Tags: php, javascript, perl

Чтобы переходя на сайте в раздел images ссылка в браузере (адрес) была не site.ru/images а site.ru.

Answer (score 2):

1. AJAX (подгружать содержимое images на главную страницу)
2. Cookies (по кнопке создаем куки "loc=/images/", обновляем, загружаем то, что в $_COOKIES['loc'])
3. POST-запросы (совсем костыль), ловить $_POST['loc']

`<form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="/images/" /><input type="submit" value="images"/></form>`

Answer (score 2):

`4.` Можно запихнуть весь контент в один большой iframe.

Comment: Кстати да, а потом `<a href="/images/" target="my_iframe">Images</a>`

Comment: Зачем? Весь сайт и так будет во фрейме. Главное - чтобы не было target="_parent" или _top.

Answer (score 0):

"Обернуть" все ссылки чем-нить вроде JQuery.
Из скрипта-обработчика подгружать контент тем же AJAX.
...или ссылки оборачивать безымянной функцией с использованием того же JQuery, у него есть методы для подгрузки контента.

Если требуется - могу рассказать подробнее, и в нескольких вариантах.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery $.load("ссылка на файл") в помощь, но если Вас заботят поисковики, то от идее с одной урл лучше отказаться.